# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION JVM crashes when using Window Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

When I double click on a button I put with Window Builder, Eclipse exit, and a `hs_err_pidXXXX` is created.

I uninstall Java, reinstall JRE or JDK.

I try both.

do some modification in eclipse.ini like add -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false, update all of plugins, eclipse, java, formatting my PC.

Some of the error file :

```
"A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff88146aca8, pid=8808, tid=0x0000000000002258

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_221-b11) (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.221-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [MSCTF.dll+0x2aca8]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See the problematic frame for where to report the bug."
```

The rest of the file is here : https://pastebin.com/S7jSZ8He

Comment: Please also mention the version of Eclipse IDE you're using. If you're using a not-so-recent one, please first consider upgrading to latest release (2019-09) and try again.

Comment: Thanks for you'r answer.
I also use the latest version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is discussed in detail here - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543747

Looks like Windows has fix for this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517211/windows-10-update-kb4517211